# probablity man is taller than woman in random pair (or comparing random values from distinct normal distributions)

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution, standard-deviation

## General Question

Suppose two populations follow normal distributions for some variable, with
population $A$ given by mean and standard deviation $\mu_A$ and $\sigma_A$, and population $B$ given by mean and standard deviation $\mu_B$ and $\sigma_B$.

For a pair of individuals consisting of one     each from *A* and *B*, the values of the variable may be given as $a$ and $b$.

**Given such a pair generated by random selection, what is the probability that $a > b$?**

## Example

For example, [according to a 2016 study](https://ourworldindata.org/human-height), the heights in the global populations of men and women are given by the following measures:

|  | Mean | Standard Deviation |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Men | 178.4 cm | 7.59 cm |
| Women | 164.7 cm | 7.07 cm |

**Taking the findings of the study,  for any random pair of   man and woman, what is the probability of the man having greater height than the woman?**

## Auxiliary Questions

1. Does the area of overlap of the two distributions have any meaningful relation to the general solution?
2. Does the height of one curve at the mean of the other curve have any meaningful relation to the general solution?

Comment: Sad the question was closed. The proposed duplicate offers only limited help, and with much effort to assimilate, respecting understanding the solution to the problem as clearly and cleanly  provided above.

Answer (score 0):

The question will probably be closed as duplicate, so let me try and quickly give some hints as how to understand the answer to the linked similar earlier question.

Let the $X$ denote the height of the man of the pair and $Y$ the height of the woman. In the general setting $X$ is a random variable with distribution $N(\mu_A, \sigma_A)$ and $Y$ a random variable with distribution $N(\mu_B, \sigma_B)$.

The answer relies on two ideas: a clever trick that is handy in many situation and a magical theorem that only applies to normal distributions and not others.

1. (Handy trick). Instead of computing the probability of the complicated event $X > Y$ which involves two random variables we first compute the new random variable $Z = X - Y$. The event we are interested in ($X > Y$) is equivalent to the simpler event $Z > 0$. So now we have to deal with only one random variable ($Z$) and we want to know when it is bigger than 0. Of course we can do that as soon as we know the distribution of $Z$
2. (Magic theorem): If two random variables $U$ and $V$ are each drawn from a normal distribution, then their sum $U + V$ is a random variable that is also drawn from a (different, but still) normal distribution!

In this case we can take $U = X$ and $V = -Y$ to see that $Z = X - Y$ follows a normal distribution as well. Of course we need to compute the mean and standard deviation of this new distribution before we can compute the probability that $Z > 0$, but it is intuitively obvious that the mean of this new distribution must be $\mu_A - \mu_B$. The rule for getting the standard deviation of $Z$ from $\sigma_A$ and $\sigma_B$ is less obvious, but you can find it in the answers to the other question.

EDIT: some remarks on the auxilary questions. Both relate to different questions than this one

1. The area of the overlap is something like this. Suppose you randomly select ONE person instead of two. Someone tells you their length and you have to guess if they are a man or a woman. You consistently make the less likely guess, i.e. if the person is 2 meters you guess female and if the person is 165cm you guess male. Then the area of the overlap is the probability that your are right.
2. The *height* of a probability distribution hardly ever has a meaningful interpretation. It is always about the area under the curve. So the area under the male curve to the right of the mean of the female curve is the probability that a randomly selected man is taller than the average woman and you can figure out the meaning of the other three variations on this theme.

Comment: Thanks for the thorough answer. I truly believe that the clean presentation of the question adds important value over the one proposed as a duplicate, and so too would an answer that is complete and accessible. (Note that using different variable designations from the question makes the complete presentation unnecessarily messy.)

Comment: If you want you can edit and change the $X$ to $a$ and $Y$ to $b$. I just hope that this answer helps you understand the situation

Comment: What is the solution?

Comment: The question 'what is the solution' sounds a bit odd to my ears The solution is this: 'Draw a normal distribution curve with mean $\mu_A - \mu_B$ and standard deviation $\sqrt(\sigma_A^2 + \sigma_B^2)$. Then the solution is the area under that curve that lies to the right of 0.' However, put like this it sounds mysterious and hard to understand. I hope that in the answer above I have given enough info for you to see where this solution comes from.

Comment: The solution would be an expression containing the four measures and evaluating to a number between $0$ and $1$.

Comment: Well that is exactly what my solution in the comment does. The entire area under the curve is 1, so if you only look at the part that is to the right of 0 you get a number that is smaller than 1, but still bigger than zero for visually obvious reasons.

Comment: It is an interesting fact about the normal distribution that this number can not be expressed 'simpler' than I just did: it can not be expressed in terms of the four numbers $\mu_A, \mu_B, \sigma_A, \sigma_B$ using only known operations like addition, multiplication and taking roots, or even sin and cos. If you want to express it as a formula you have to introduce the new symbol $\Phi$ as the other answer does. But $\Phi(x)$ literally means 'the part of the area under a normal distribution curve with mean 0 and sd 1 that lies to the left of $x$' so it is no improvement over what I just wrote

Comment: The "interesting fact" you mention is the definition of the [error function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function), is it not?

Comment: Well, $\Phi$ is the error function, the interesting fact is that it cannot be expressed in terms of other simpler functions

Comment: Why is the distinction relevant?

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood you, but I described the solution in terms of area under a curve that depended on the four parameters $\mu_A, \mu_B, \sigma_A, \sigma_B$ and I thought you said you wanted it a solution that depended *only* on this four numbes, so not involving words like 'area under the curve'. But the only way to do that is to express this area as a sum/product/something of these numbers, so it is relevant that that is not possible

Comment: Vincent, What is the solution to the question, given as an expression containing the four measures (and including one or more uses of the error function, as needed, as well as any other well-known functions, as needed)?

Comment: If we temporarily write $\Psi$ for the cdf of the distribution of $a - b$ (so normal with mean $\mu_A - \mu_B$ and sd $\sqrt{\sigma_A^2 + \sigma_B^2}$ then in general we have $\Psi(x) = \Phi(\frac{x - (\mu_A - \mu_B)}{\sqrt{\sigma_A^2 + \sigma_B^2}})$ (Do you see why??). Now we are interested in the probability of the difference $a - b$ being bigger than zero. This equals $1 - \Psi(0) = 1 - \Phi(\frac{\mu_B - \mu_A}{\sqrt{\sigma_A^2 + \sigma_B^2}})$

Comment: We can write it more beautifully as $\Phi(\frac{\mu_A - \mu_B}{\sqrt{\sigma_A^2 + \sigma_B^2}})$ by exploiting the symmetry in the normal distribution.

Comment: But in the end it is more important that you understand how we got there, so you can reconstruct it yourself if you ever forget the formula

Comment: Thank you. I would consider the solution you have just given as an important part of a complete answer.